# ¿Sabéis por qué no me entra en el Servicio Web esta llamada con Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
 $("#txbDNINom").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var Prefix = $("#txbDNINom").val();
        var parametres = "{'prefix':'" + Prefix + "'}";
        alert("entra al source:function");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/WebServiceCVAdmin.asmx/ObtenirUsuarisCVJSON", // crida servei web k retornarà llista de objectes amb json
            data: parametres, // passo el paràmetre CP per a filtrar la consulta
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("entra al success");
                var valors = JSON.parse(data.d);
                response($.map(valors, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.NIF,
                        label: item.Nom
                    };
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("entra al ERROR " + +response.responseText);
                $("#Hidtxt").val("");

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("entra al FAILURE " + +response.responseText);
                $("#Hidtxt").val("");                   
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        NomTitol = i.item.label;
        $("#Hidtxt").val(i.item.value);
    },
    minLength: 2 //mínim de caràcters per a que comenci a buscar
});
```

No hay manera de que me entre al servicio web de la url (La ruta esta bien, pues esta dentro la carpeta principal con ese nombre) ya que tengo puntos de interrupción en la función del servicoo web y no llega a entrar para debugar.
Me entra al "error" de Ajax y el alert me dice: NaN (non a number) y no entiendo el porqué de este mensaje de error ni porque no entra al servicio web(otra cosa es que entrase y a dentro hubiera error en el código, pero es que no entra al archivo de servicios web)....

Comment: si tomas la url  http://<sitio>/WebServiceCVAdmin.asmx y la pones en el browser esta resuelve mostrandote la pagina por defecto del asmx? esto para validar que el servicio resuelve de forma correcta

Comment: He ejecutado los servicios web y puedo elegir el servicio a utilizar y entrarle los parámetros y debugar...

Answer (score 1):

Vale, me faltaba la etiqueta [ScriptService] en la clase del servicio web... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Son 2 cosas las que tienes que revisar (en tu asmx)

1. La clase del webservice debe tener el **ScriptService**
2. El método al que estas llamando debe tener **ScriptMethod**

Answer (score 0):

antes que lo pongas en producción, te recomiendo que hagas un `console.log(data)` y `console.log(response)` antes de los `alert`

Y retirar el segundo signo de suma, con esto evitas el NaN

```
alert("entra al ERROR " + response.responseText);
```

Comment: Vale ufff, no me habia fijado ene l segundo signo de suma...

Comment: solucionado? o sigue algún error por ahí?

Comment: sigue sin entrar al servicio web, el error ahora es: error: [object Object]